# Fully qualified url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

Is there a way to find out the fully qualified url in Nodejs?

Basically I want to crawl a website using my custom node.js based crawler. I fetch all the anchor tags and make http requests on them. The problem is that I am not able to figure out the exact url that I need to make the request to. Please help

Example URLS

`http://aaa.com/bbb`

`//aaa.com/bbb` or `//aaa/bbb`

`/aaa.com/bbb` or `/aaa/bbb`

`aaa.com/bbb` or `aaa/bbb`

Comment: have you heard about `url.join()`?

Comment: But the urls are specified in different formats every where. A simple join will not solve the problem. I need an algo in place to do that.

Comment: `url.join()` + `url.resolve()` can do the magic, just provide some examples where you can not use them

Comment: @micnic I added some sample urls that I would like to get the fully qualified urls of.

Answer (score 1):

The [url.resolve](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) feature worked for me (suggested by @Karman and @micnic). The first argument was the base url, which represented the url of the page that I was scraping for anchor tags. The second argument is the url which is saved in the `href` tag of the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the url module http://nodejs.org/api/url.html
you can use url resolve property or have detail look at the above mentioned documentation of url module

also e.g.

```
var obj=  require('url').parse('http://google.com?q=tobi');
will result in
obj= 
{ protocol: 'http:',
slashes: true,
host: 'google.com',
hostname: 'google.com',
href: 'http://google.com/?q=tobi',
search: '?q=tobi',
query: 'q=tobi',
pathname: '/' }
```

Comment: This would fail for 'aaa/bbbb'. Even though its a valid url on the page.

Comment: Good. Share your code about how u resolve it so it might also helps others. Also accpet the post as answer